# ElasticSearch filter by terms issue

Tags: elasticsearch

faced an interesting issue on filter by terms on field `state`:

if I will remove terms from filter block - all good, if I will add term\terms nothing will be found

as Example

```
curl -X GET "http://elasticsearch:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u "elastic:pwd"  -d'
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "sort": [
    {
      "campaign.priority": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "giftStatusId": [
              10
            ]
          }
        }

      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*68561*"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "giftId": "68561"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "state":
              "complete"

          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}'
{
 "took" : 32,
 "timed_out" : false,
 "_shards" : {
   "total" : 1,
   "successful" : 1,
   "skipped" : 0,
   "failed" : 0
 },
 "hits" : {
   "total" : {
     "value" : 1,
     "relation" : "eq"
   },
   "max_score" : null,
   "hits" : [
     {
       "_index" : "research",
       "_id" : "190823",
       "_score" : null,
       "_source" : {
         "id" : 190823,
         "agent" : 1045,
         "giftId" : 68561,
         "sender" : {
           "firstName" : "TeamOwner",
           "lastName" : "Internal.alyce.gifts.GiftCampaignDetailsTests",
           "email" : "1203110345eeJq_@test.comz"
         },
         "recipient" : {
           "id" : 20220,
           "firstName" : "Contact",
           "lastName" : "lastName_lmfk",
           "email" : "1203110416VTLR_@contactEmail.comz"
         },
         "campaign" : {
           "id" : 3981,
           "name" : "campaign_UhGw",
           "priority" : 0,
           "organizationId" : "1487",
           "organizationName" : "Org_hABD",
           "teamId" : 2785,
           "teamName" : "1203110359bWht_Team"
         },
         "state" : "unclaimedAuto",
         "createdAt" : "2020-12-03T11:06:26+00:00",
         "updatedAt" : "2020-12-08T09:27:28+00:00",
         "giftStatusId" : 10
       },
       "sort" : [
         0
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

All good above, but below nothing found

```
curl -X GET "http://elasticsearch:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u "elastic:pwd"  -d'
 {
   "from": 0,
   "size": 10000,
   "sort": [
     {
       "campaign.priority": {
         "order": "desc"
       }
     }
   ],
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must": [
         {
           "terms": {
             "giftStatusId": [
               10
             ]
           }
         },
         {
           "terms": {
             "state": [
               "unclaimedAuto"
             ]
           }
         }
       ],
       "should": [
         {
           "query_string": {
             "query": "*68561*"
           }
         },
         {
           "term": {
             "giftId": "68561"
           }
         }
       ],
       "minimum_should_match": 1
     }
   }
 }'
{
  "took" : 29,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone faced same issue?

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `state` field? My guess is that it's of type `text` instead of `keyword`

Comment: default mapper, no specific was set

Comment: I've put state filtering logic into query_string and it works fine

Comment: `query_string` and `term(s)` are two very different beasts

Comment: @Val yep, just have not find a better way to do *term* for all fields, alternative to SQL LIKE %term%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Val pointed out the `state` field should be of `keyword` type.

This is because if you are using [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) it returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field. And, for [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) it returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field. **So, in both the queries, you need to have an exact match.**

So either you can change the data type of the `state` field to `keyword` type

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "state": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

OR if you have not explicitly defined any mapping, then you can also modify your search query like this :

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "sort": [
    {
      "campaign.priority": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "giftStatusId": [
              10
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "state.keyword": [      ---> note this
              "unclaimedAuto"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*68561*"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "giftId": "68561"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after state field)

Comment: @beebop looking forward to get an update from you :)

Comment: @beebop if my answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer as well :)